# Buildfire: Confirm notifcation behavior differs (and fails) in control panel and device but works in localhost

Tags: buildfire

I am seeing an issue when attempting to use the confirm notifications functionality. It works fine in the dev environment but when uploaded and testing in the control panel or application it doesn't work. The callback returns a null data object and err=true where in the dev environment the data object has the selected button key available to action on. This is the only way to distinguish between the confirm button and cancel button being pressed (for the confirm notification).

The confirm notification documentation is here:
https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-use-Notifications

The console output for the success (in dev/localhost):
[Success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67QGm.jpg)

The console output for the same code in the control panel (and device):
[Failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJjkw.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug that is being worked on. Here is an ugly workaround.

```
buildfire.notifications.confirm({message:"Are you sure you want to delete this epic?",confirmButton:{type:"danger"}},(e,r)=>{
                if(e==1 || r.selectedButton.key == "confirm" ){ // confirmed }};
```